# What will happen if I change kernel configuration file in /boot?

Tags: linux, configuration, kernel

I'm trying to understand all role of `/boot/config-$kernel_version` file.
I know I can see current kernel feature configuration from `/boot/config-$kernel_version` and I know I can make with my desirable kernel feature config file with use of config tool to create a .config file in `/usr/src/linux-*` directory.
but what exactly is this `/boot/config*` file for? I can't find any good explanation any where
is it just an archive file? Or what will happen if I change some configuration in here?
Or can someone share good link that describe this matter properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: the `/boot/config-....` file shows the configuration used used to compile the corresponding kernel. Most people run distros, and do not compile their own kernels. Therefore, the presence of this file is generally useless. At best, it can allow some information if the user faces kernel problems, as it gives the exact configuration used during compilation. Modifying it will not have any effect on the system.

On the other hand, for those who do compile their own kernels, for development, testing or experimentation, this provides a good starting point. For example, if I am running Ubuntu, and I have the kernel source (with Ubuntu patches), the config file will allow me to compile my own, identical kernel. Then, I can experiment with what changes to the source or the config have.....